# Does macOS support AnyIP?

Tags: macos, network, command-line, osx-server, ipv6

I would like to assign a complete block to my Mac as described in this question: [Can I bind a (large) block of addresses to an interface?](https://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface)

There it is explained that AnyIP is supported for IPv6 by the Linux Kernel and how to configure it on your device, but the command being used is `ip`, which seems not available on macOS. If this technique is supported on **macOS, what is the command to achieve the same?**

PS. I know how to add a single IPv6 to an interface using the command `ifconfig -r -L en1 inet6 fe80::2/64 alias`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature is not supported on macOS.

Depending on how many IP addresses you want to listen to, you could use a simple script to bind each IP-address to the interface individually using the ifconfig alias command.